# coreNLP- r package annotateString gives Null openie

Tags: r, stanford-nlp

I am new in using the R coreNLP package. I just installed the package with the objective to  use the function getOpenIE. However, even when I run the code on a very simple sentence.The annotateString function doesn't work for annotating openie. See the below code:

```
library(coreNLP)
downloadCoreNLP()
initCoreNLP()
text <- "food is good and staff is friendly"
t <- annotateString(text)
> t$openie
NULL
 > getOpenIE(t)
 NULL
```

Is this a common issue? has anyone found a solution yet? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this too. You need to add`type = "english_all"` when using the  `initCoreNLP` function. See a working reprex below:

```r
library(coreNLP)
#> Warning: package 'coreNLP' was built under R version 3.4.4
downloadCoreNLP()
#> [1] 0
initCoreNLP(type = "english_all")
text <- "food is good and staff is friendly"
t <- annotateString(text)
t$openie
#>   subject_start subject_end subject relation_start relation_end relation
#> 1             4           5   staff              5            6       is
#> 2             0           1    food              1            2       is
#>   object_start object_end   object
#> 1            6          7 friendly
#> 2            2          3     good
getOpenIE(t)
#>   subject_start subject_end subject relation_start relation_end relation
#> 1             4           5   staff              5            6       is
#> 2             0           1    food              1            2       is
#>   object_start object_end   object
#> 1            6          7 friendly
#> 2            2          3     good
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>